# How do I step through a referenced assembly in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dllregistration

I have a referenced assembly that keeps failing when I call it. I have the source for this assembly in a large project, Project A. I've compiled it and have been using it in Project B. Unfortunately Project B keeps failing and the stack trace shows that it fails on Project A's assembly.

It seems like I have two options:

- Add Project A to Project B, change all references to the assembly to the project. This seems like it'd be a lot of work.
- Use some third party tool, like Reflector, to step through the assembly.

Is there any other way I'm missing it? Is there anyway to link the projects easily?

Sorry if this sounds naive. it is the first time I've run into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you have source code of project A

just include PDB file and assign referecne of the project A dll.

when you reach method of prject A press f11 which will take you to project A.

Answer (score 6):

Add `ProjectA.pdb` to the folder that you're referencing the DLL from and Visual Studio should pick up the debugging symbols and step in automatically.